# Changing Views' position in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to build a simple app where there's a button and each time it gets clicked, it changes its location on the screen. I don't have any experience at all developing for android so I don't know how to change the view's properties etc.

```
package com.example.button_chaser

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.random.Random

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var button: Button
    lateinit var text: TextView
    var score = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        var text: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.score)

        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

        var width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        var height = displayMetrics.heightPixels

        println(width)
        println(height)

        button.setOnClickListener{
            score += 1
            text.text = "Score: $score"

            button.x = Random.nextInt(width).toFloat()
            button.y = Random.nextInt(height).toFloat()
        }

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and enjoy :)

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_relativeLayout"  // add id to RelativeLayout
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click !" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
     binding.myBtn.setOnClickListener {
        
      val random = Random
      val relativeLayout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.my_relativeLayout)
            
         binding.show.x = random.nextInt(relativeLayout.width - binding.show.width).toFloat()
         binding.show.y = random.nextInt(relativeLayout.height - binding.show.height).toFloat()
        
 }
```

Comment: Am I supposed to import a package for the random function?

Comment: yes import kotlin.random.Random

Comment: but now sometimes the button goes off the screen, how can I set limits for the random values so they match each users' screen width and height properties? surely there's a way right?

Comment: Yes it can be done. I have updated the code

Comment: well, now the relativeLayout line makes the app fail to run in the emulator and crash... wtf

Comment: Make sure you write id in relative layout

Comment: I did, exactly as it appears in the code you posted

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: idk how to see the exception in android studio, this is the error that appears in the logcat
"2022-01-11 19:03:47.523 1787-2356/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8"

Comment: I added my code above and now it runs ok, but how can I get the true dimensions of the screen estate that the app takes, since sometimes the button is placed out of the screen making it impossible to click